# is [function class:me() end] equal to [function class.me(self) end] in lua?

Tags: lua, operator-keyword

I am having a little hard time to understand the colon operator in lua. So I did some experiment on colon operator and came up with this conclusion.

```
class = {}

function class:me()
end
```

is equal to

```
function class.me(self)
end
```

Am I making a right conclusion?

If not, what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Your conclusion is correct.

The : form is just syntactic sugar for the . form with self as the first parameter.  This is documented:

> The colon syntax is used for defining methods, that is, functions
>   that have an implicit extra parameter self. Thus, the statement
>
> ```
>  function t.a.b.c:f (params) body end
> ```
>
> is syntactic sugar for
>
> ```
>  t.a.b.c.f = function (self, params) body end
> ```

Comment: Yes, and even more generally, in these examples, `class` and `t.a.b.c` are expressions.